# Input field gives hints from MySQL as user types

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "contacts" and "companies". When the user types a company in the add "contact" form i need it to give hints as to companies that may match in the "company" table. This is an attempt to reduce redundancy in the company fields.

I am not sure if this is possible with php and mysql and i hope my explanation is adequate.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a JavaScript autocomplete/AJAX solution would work.

Comment: I am not sure how javascript or ajax could access the database?

Comment: ajax could access a php file which could access the database and retrieve records, pass them back to javascript and voala! check this autocompleter: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: it's call "typeahead", and there's literally thousands of examples of it all over the web.

Comment: @user114236, AJAX accesses databases by asking a server-side script to make the query in its place; the server-side script then returns the results of the query in a format that the AJAX can interpret (a JSON string, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side technology. MySQL is a database technology. Neither will (on their own) create an autocomplete field.

You need a client-side technology to achieve what you want; in this case, I can almost guarantee that the best solution for you is JavaScript. You could potentially roll your own autocomplete, or you could use someone else's library. One such library is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), which includes an [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget. (Note that jQuery UI requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).)

For an atuocomplete field, you could either build it completely client-side, storing all values in the JavaScript, or you could use AJAX to pull values from your MySQL database as needed, without reloading the page (something you definitely don't want to do for an autocomplete field). The jQuery UI autocomplete documentation has examples of doing exactly that.